# Mysql Innodb Optimize table

Tags: mysql, database

I have a 100Gb innodb table on C:\ drive and the C:\ drive is out of space now.I deleted many rows but the the ibd file did not shrink.
I have more than 200Gb available on D:\drive and subsequently configured tmpdir to be in d:\drive and tried to optimize table .But when I optimize table it is taking up whatever space is left on c:\ drive and not using d:\

What parameter should I change?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot shrink the innodb data file (default name is `ibdata1`) without deleting it :S .

Using innodb engine you should use `innodb_file_per_table=1`

To solve you space issue you should:

1) Execute a full database backup: `mysqldump -u root -pMyPassword -R --all-databases > full.sql`

2) Stop mysql service

3) Add (or change value of) the parameter `innodb_file_per_table=1`

4) Drop the existing innodb data file (`/$mysqldir/ibdata1`)

5) Start mysql service

6) Restore the backup: `mylsql -u root -pMyPassword mysql < full.sql`

Now the innodb data file will not growth too much anymore, and an optimize table will allow you to shrink the involve table data file since now each table will amnage it's own data file.

Using symbolic links (at least under Linux), it allows you to locate databases on different disks.

Answer (score 0):

There is tmpdir parameter for that. And I think you can set that with

```
SET GLOBAL tmpdir = D:/temp
```

before any optimization operation or add following under mysld

```
set-variable = tmpdir=/var/tmp
```

As a bonus I strongly suggest you to use

```
innodb_file_per_table=1
```

to have separate file for each table if of course you have innodb tables.
And also using compressed data will reduce your disk usage.